# Batch file to delete only files older than n days

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to delete log files older than 2 days recursively from a root folder.  I wrote what I though would work but it also deletes **folders** if they are also older than 2 days.  Can I modify this script to accomplish my goal of just purging **files**?, or is there a better way to skin this cat?

```
    set destinationDir=\\sqlbackupslas\SQLDataBackup\TESTING\CTM-A-Server
    pushd %destinationDir%
    echo "Deleting files from "%destinationDir%
    ForFiles /s /d -2  /c "cmd /c echo "deleting..." & echo @file"  <-- this is for testing, I'll change it to a delete
    popd
```

Comment: read the output of `forfiles /?`. Note the example in the very last line.

Comment: As already mentioned by @Stephan, open a Command Prompt window, type `forfiles /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for the command you're using! You should clearly see `if @isdir==FALSE`. Your question is off topic, because you have clearly not read the standard built-in help for your problematic command. Future users will not benefit from any answers which tell them to read this essential information before posting a question or seeking assistance with a command.